# Realm causing lots of ANR

Tags: android, realm

In my own testing I did not encounter this issue but once my app was published the ANRs started flooding in. My app currently has 22 ANRs with some being reported as many 100 times. All of the traces seem to be from attempting to create a new Realm instance on the UI thread.

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 MONITOR
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4183ede0 self=0x417548b8
| sysTid=19680 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073975684
| state=S schedstat=( 2816413167 710323137 3658 ) utm=215 stm=66 core=1
at io.realm.Realm.createAndValidate(Realm.java:~495)
- waiting to lock <0x41df9c98> held by tid=12          (IntentService[UASyncService])
at io.realm.Realm.create(Realm.java:486)
at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:404)
at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:366)
at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:347)
```

I believe the root of this issue is, as beeender mentioned, that I have an open Realm transaction in a worker thread which is blocking my attempts to get a Realm instance on the UI thread causing ANRs.

I will update again later after I have a solution.

*Edit: Added updated information.

Comment: It seems you have a write transaction which is not closed. This could block the Realm to open new instance.  Check this PR https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/1297 .  If it is the case, I suggest you close your transaction properly instead of waiting for the fix since the write transaction needs to be closed anyway.

Comment: @beeender So if I begin a transaction on a worker thread and try to open a new Realm instance on the UI thread before the worker thread transaction is committed, the UI thread will be blocked waiting for the transaction to be committed?

Comment: Right now, yes. Although i don't think it is the right behaviour, There might be some reasons for the current behaviour which i am not aware of. Now, when create a Realm instance in one thread, and there is no opened instance in the thread yet, createAndValidate will be called and it might blocked by transaction in other threads. But if there is one opened instance in the thread already, a reference will be returned without creation.

Comment: In that case, opening a single Realm in onCreate (stupid process death) or when there are more activities/services/etc than one will actually prevent this problem from occurring for me. Neat!

Comment: Technically, I'm using a singleton realm in `Application onCreate()` and do lots of magic to ensure it's always open, but with 0.83.0 and anything above, I was getting lots of ANRs for whatever reason. I should have sent Realm source code to reproduce this issue like a month ago now, though; so all the blame is on me at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realm no longer has this issue.

For reference my solution at the time was:

Thanks to beeender for pointing me in the right direction and linking this PR https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/1297

**Issue**

When there is a pending Realm transaction, any call to `Realm.getInstance` on a different thread will block until the pending transaction has been committed or cancelled.

In my case I have an IntentService which populates my Realm with existing user data, meanwhile I try to display any current data by querying Realm on the UI thread. Although the queries are simple and don't cause any issues normally, if there is a pending transaction in the IntentService, calling `Realm.getInstance` will be blocked, blocking the UI thread, potentially causing an ANR.

My first attempt at a solution was to pull beeender's PR branch and create a jar. I believe this fix did get me one step further, allowing the Realm instance to be created without blocking, but the UI thread was still blocked by small transactions I was trying to perform on UI thread.

**Solution**

The solution I implemented involves several steps:

- Create duplicate objects for all of my models. The duplicates do not extend RealmObject (since RealmObjects cannot be used across threads.)
- Move all accesses to Realm onto background threads. Basically I wrapped my queries in AsyncTasks and added listeners which return the non-RealmObject version of the model.
- Make more small transactions rather than fewer large transactions. Where previously I began and committed transactions on either side of a loop which created many new RealmObjects, I now begin and commit the transaction per object. The purpose of this is to reduce the total uninterrupted time that Realm may be in an open transaction state so my queries providing data for the UI can complete without having to wait as long.

**Conclusion**

I was initially hesitant to use Realm due to it still being in beta as well as the caveat that RealmObjects cannot be used across threads. After some tests I felt confident that I could perform simple queries on the UI thread without issue (still with a guilty feeling in my gut though.)

Overall Realm is a great project to keep an eye on but I feel that it is not ready for large scale commercial projects. Using Realm on this project may have saved some time upfront but it cost many displeased customers and a difficult to diagnose issue.

*Edit: Clarified issue.

Comment: With that PR, getInstance should not be blocked anymore. Is there anyway i can reproduce your issue? Is it possible that you compiled with the PR, but used a wrong jar? Shall i compile a jar for you and help me to verify? Thanks! The only case i can imagine right now is you created an instance in other thread and immediately after that a writeTransaction started. And before the instance created, another thread trying to create an instance as well, and start waiting for transaction unlock already. Let check if i can figure out how to solve that.

Comment: @beeender As I mentioned, your fix did get me further in that `getInstance` was no longer blocked but I still had an issue. I was also doing a small transaction on the UI thread and this transaction was blocked by the transaction in my IntentService so I needed to rework things anyways.

Comment: Would you please update you answer a bit since it is not a problem anymore :) and https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/1297 has been merged to make sure this won't happen again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Realm's introduction example](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/introExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/intro/IntroExampleActivity.java) shows them using an AsyncTask to do their reads and writes.

Any costly I/O, be it from the network, a database, or a large file should typically be kept off the main thread as it will cause a sluggish UI. Without seeing your code, I'd guess that if you're getting an ANR you're probably doing something too complex for the main thread.

Comment: Any significant reads or writes I am doing is being performed on a worker thread in an IntentService. The only Realm access I am doing on the main thread is fairly simple queries.

Comment: You should try to enable StrictMode to make sure your application is not doing any operations that would impact the UI.